# Is there any way to pass values from one page to another other than GET AND POST in JSP?

Tags: jsp

For instance I have a page form.jsp contaiing a form and process.jsp that does all processing on the received data. When I submit data from page form.jsp,it goes to process.jsp which does all the processing and creates a table. I want to send this table to form.jsp.Is there any way to do thi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do the postprocessing in a JSP. [Use a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 1):

Use `response.sendredirect("form.jsp")`. You can add your table in session and access it in form.jsp. Also can use url like `"form.jsp?table"+tableData` in response.sendredirect.

Comment: Is it possible to encode the table data so that users cannot see the values?

Comment: @Vimal: what exactly your requirement is? encode table data in url or encode the table data itself?

Answer (score 0):

You would use [Encode URL Redirect](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29) for encoding your URL.